# How can the ask price be higher than the bid price in the stock market?

Tags: bid-ask

I recently checked the bid and ask price in the Apple stock, and I found that the ask price was higher than the bid. Why is this?
[Apple Stock Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhTSq.png)

I thought that bid was supposed to be higher than the ask.

Comment: Read This: [In a normal correctly functioning market, the bid should always be below the ask](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/85587/when-should-i-buy-or-sell-in-an-otc-market/88761#88761)

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why you think that the bid should be higher than the ask. This way, we would be able to directly address whatever misunderstanding you may have.

Comment: Perhaps your confusion is similar to this: [How do market makers profit from the bid-ask spread when bids are almost always lower than asks?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/125681/how-do-market-makers-profit-from-the-bid-ask-spread-when-bids-are-almost-always)